# JavaScript to retrieve value from Grid

Tags: javascript

I have a `RowDataBound` event as follows.

```
protected void GridLedger_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseDown", "var str = document.getElementById('" + e.Row.ClientID + "').cells[0].innerText; document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value = str;");
    } 
}
```

When this event fires, I am getting the following error:

`object element not found or not an object`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: hai. pls take the time to compose proper sentences k?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the jQuery library or any other javascript framework to make your life a LOT easier.

This errors seems to me that you either can't find the object you are looking for or the property cells does not exist. This might even differ from browser to browser ...

Have a look at your generated code and see what the ID of that error is ...